# JSDoc Class suggested layout

Tags: jsdoc

I'm brand new to JSDoc, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to tag my code.  For some reason after I label something as a @class, I can't get anything to appear as @inner:

```
/**
 * The logger, to simply output logs to the console (or potentially a variable)
 * @class Logger
 * @requires 'config/globalConfig'
 */
define(["config/globalConfig"], function (config) {
    /**
     * Instantiate a new copy of the logger for a class/object
     * @constructor
     * @param name {string} - The name of the class instantiating the logger
     */
    return function (name) {
        /**
         * @memberOf Logger
         * @type {string}
         */
        this.name = name;

        /**
         * Place the message on the console, only for "DEV" level debugging
         * @function
         * @memberOf Logger
         * @param message {string}
         */
        this.debug = function (message) {
            ... some code ...
        };         
    };
});
```

Right now all the members are appearing as <static>.  If I add the @inner tag to any of the attributes/functions they vanish completely from the output.

Edit: I also forgot to mention.  The @constructor flag doesn't seem to be working either.  If I remove that entire section, it appears the same in the output.  The output does not include the @param that I would like to mention with my constructor.

Please let me know if this is completely off, I'm just kind of guessing here since the JSDoc3 documentation is a bit difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, still not sure if it's absolutely correct.  I had to use "Logger~name" to have it appear correctly as an inner function.  According to the JSDoc documentation, this ~ is "rarely used".  Seems to be the only thing that works for me.

```
define(["config/globalConfig"], function (config) {
    /**
     * The logger, to simply output logs to the console (or potentially a variable)
     * @class Logger
     * @param name {string} - The name of the class instantiating the logger
     */
    return function (name) {
        this.name = name;

        /**
         * Place the message on the console, only for "DEV" level debugging
         * @function Logger~debug
         * @param message {string}
         */
        this.debug = function (message) {
            ... code ...
        };
    };
});
```